# setting .zshrc for arq jena

Tags: osx-mavericks, jena, zshrc, arq

I'm trying to set my .zshrc file to export ARQROOT for ARQ (jena) on a mac (mavericks), similar to what is shown on http://jena.sourceforge.net/ARQ/Tutorial/query1.html for windows and linux

tried all sorts of combinations with paths, quotes and syntax but none seems to work. Any thoughts on what the mac/zsh equivalent to export ARQROOT=$HOME/MyProjects/ARQ would be?

many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ARQROOT isn't needed nowadays.

The scripts (in apache-jena-VERSION/bin or /bat) set paths themselves.

The Jena project is now at http://jena.apache.org/ (how did you get to the sourceforge page? It's supposed to redirect).

Comment: you got it, was using the wrong version. works perfectly now. thanks